# Way to generate a code that creates a constructor based on the current values of an object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-generation

What I want to achieve is after loading my object from the database, to generate a code that will give me a block which initializes my object based on its current values so that I can use this code-block in my unit tests again and again without loading it from Db anymore.

Is there any tool around to achieve such a goal for VS?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could serialize the instance of the object into either XML or binary file and use this file in your unit test to deserialize it back to the instance.